# How can I add to props and make a select option disabled?

Tags: reactjs

I have a dropdown list which I am getting from a list that is part of props. A Visual of how the props look like when I do `console.log(props.farmAnimals)`

```
  {id: "CA", name : "Cat"}
  {id: "DG", name : "Dog"}
  {id: "HN", name : "Hen"}
  {id: "PG", name : "Pig"}
```

I want to make the dropdown have the name `Dog` appear twice and have a non-selectable `-----` as part of the dropdown options just after `Dog`. I want it to look like this

```
  {id: "DG", name : "Dog"}
  {id: "--", name : "----"}
  {id: "CA", name : "Cat"}
  {id: "DG", name : "Dog"}
  {id: "HN", name : "Hen"}
  {id: "PG", name : "Pig"}
```

How can I achieve this? I also need the `---` to be non-selectable.

Comment: Would you please share more details about what you tried so far and what issue you're actually facing? The goal you're describing in the post seems as straightforward as: (1) creating a new array with the additional two items plus all the items from `farmAnimals`; (2) adding a `disabled` attribute to `<option>` when `id == '--'`

Comment: @lbsn since it's an array I don't know how to add the attribute disabled to the second element on the array

Answer (score 0):

Based on the information you provide I guess you can just:

(1) create a new array with the additional items:

```
const list = [
  { id: 'DG', name: 'Dog' },
  { id: '--', name: '----' },
  ...farmAnimals,
];
```

(2) disable the `<option>` whose item has id '--':

```
  <select>
    {list.map((item, index) => (
      <option value={item.id} key={index} disabled={item.id === '--'}>
        {item.name}
      </option>
    ))}
  </select>
```